# access rights allow modifications and deny delete

Tags: powershell, acl, access-rights

I have following PowerShell script.
I would like to allow users to create files and folders and name them as they like + access them and write into them BUT I would also like to prevent users from deleting folders and files.
If I remove "Modify" they cannot rename files and folders
If I add Modify they can rename but also can delete file.
What am I doing wrong?

```
Add-NTFSAccess -Path '\\fileshare\path' -Account 'QC_PDQC_spec' -AccessType Allow -AppliesTo ThisFolderSubfoldersAndFiles -AccessRights 'GenericRead', 'GenericWrite', 'Traverse', 'createFiles', 'CreateDirectories' , 'Modify';
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly add a `Deny` ACE for the `Delete` right on top of the `Allow` ACE for `Modify`:

```
Add-NTFSAccess -Path '\\fileshare\path' -Account 'QC_PDQC_spec' -AccessType Allow -AppliesTo ThisFolderSubfoldersAndFiles -AccessRights GenericRead,GenericWrite,Traverse,CreateFiles,CreateDirectories,Modify
Add-NTFSAccess -Path '\\fileshare\path' -Account 'QC_PDQC_spec' -AccessType Deny -AppliesTo ThisFolderSubfoldersAndFiles -AccessRights Delete
```

Comment: This is what I run, but unfortunately users can create files but not rename, so it's just "new folder 1" "new folder 2" etc.  [gist](https://gist.github.com/xnekv03/abfebf7632baf663bbff6de9e09208c1)